# Mahalanobis distance returns NaN in Pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, distance, pytorch, mahalanobis

I'm testing new metrics to measure distance between weight matrices in Pytorch, right now I'm trying to use Mahalanobis. For that I reshape every matrix into a vector and concat then into one matrix and then use this matrix to calculate the mahalanobis distance between any two rows of this matrix. Problem is some of those are getting me negative results and the square root of a negative throws me NaN.

I know the covariance matrix has to be Positive Defined, I guess I'm messing up there, or maybe my ideia of using mahalanobis in this case is not possible?

Here's the code I'm using, where I'm passing to it a X with shape (64,121), that being 64 (11x11) matrices

```
def _mahalanobis(X):
    VI = torch.inverse(cov(X)) #covariance matrix
    total_dist = 0
    for i,v in enumerate(X):
        dist = 0
        for j,u in enumerate(X):
            if i == j:
                continue
            x = (v-u).unsqueeze(0).t()
            y = (v - u).unsqueeze(0)

            dist = torch.sqrt(torch.mm(torch.mm(y,VI),x))

            total_dist +=dist
            print(dist)
    return total_dist


## Returns the covariance matrix of m
    def cov(m, rowvar=False):

        if m.dim() > 2:
            raise ValueError('m has more than 2 dimensions')
        if m.dim() < 2:
            m = m.view(1, -1)
        if not rowvar and m.size(0) != 1:
            m = m.t()
        # m = m.type(torch.double)  # uncomment this line if desired
        fact = 1.0 / (m.size(1) - 1)
        m -= torch.mean(m, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        mt = m.t()  # if complex: mt = m.t().conj()
        return fact * m.matmul(mt).squeeze()
```

Comment: are you sure `cov(X)` is positive definite? is it possible it is only _semi_ definite? your negative `dist`: how negative are they? are they very close to zero (indicating numerical instability that can be safely rouned to zero), or are they significantly far from zero?

Comment: @Shai a) yes, I think it is possible for it to be only semi definite, I'm not sure. If so, would that indicate an inconsistency within my data? b) Some negatives go down to -300, they are quite significantly far from zero. c) Is there any reason why mahalanobis wouldn't apply to weight matrix in a neural network?